# Can we make copy / download published Google Docs shared by others?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, google-workspace

I have a Google Doc link which looks something like this:

> https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTka35LEjmhp_0Fa8hUkWJazZSkGG5tO0phXt9lKrFdeh0nbPv-YyVjhsZGgGmdWWXELA9yl-ZXCesU/pub

You can click on above and see how it renders without any number.

I am am able to save it as html. Am also able to print it as PDF, but it somewhat screws up the format.

So, can I make copy of such published docs shared by others in my own drive? Or if not copy can I download them as docx (Microsoft word) file or PDF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays the published to the web URL from a Google Document can't b used to make a copy / download the corresponding Google Document. If you are able to contact the document owner ask them to share the document with you.

Resources

- [Publish a document, spreadsheet, presentation, or drawing - Google Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en)

Comment: yes I realise that  published document is not a document itself. Instead its a website with its own webpage. So, by nature it makes no sense to make its copy or download as in case of docs.